# Emit one value with EventEmitter angular

Tags: angular

I Have four values of products (A,B,C,D) (between a tag ).
I create a child component angular and I want to pass a good value  (A or B or Cor D) to parent component with EventEmitter.emit when user click but i doesn't can. I send always the first value A.
This is my angular code

component.html

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <th><a #ca [attr.data-cat]="alax" (click)="getName(ca.dataset.cat)">A</a></th>
      <th><a #ca [attr.data-cat]="beter" (click)="getName(ca.dataset.cat)">B</a></th>
      <th><a #ca [attr.data-cat]="colar" (click)="getName(ca.dataset.cat)">C</a></th>
      <th><a #ca [attr.data-cat]="dera" (click)="getName(ca.dataset.cat)">D</a></th>
   </thead>
</table>
```

In component.ts

```
alax= 'ARMOIRS';
beter= 'PARASOLS';
colar= 'CAMBOUS';
dera= 'DIAMBRE';

 @Output()
 sendRequestData = new EventEmitter(); 

 getName(catName:string) {
  console.log("catName nom : "+catName);
  this.sendRequestData.emit(catName);
}
```

In the father component.html I have :

```
<app-chilComponent (sendRequestData)="treatment($event)"></app-childComponent>
```

In father component.ts

```
treatment(message: any){
 console.log(message) // I have always 'ARMOIRS' when I click on A or B or C or D
                      // I want to have 'ARMOIS' when I click on A and 'PARASOLS' when i click on B
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: what values are coming in console inside child locally, (not after emitting) when the getName() triggers? Kindly check and tell.

Answer (score 1):

You have used the same selector `#ca` for all. Change them

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <th><a #ca1 [attr.data-cat]="alax" (click)="getName(ca1.dataset.cat)">A</a></th>
      <th><a #ca2 [attr.data-cat]="beter" (click)="getName(ca2.dataset.cat)">B</a></th>
      <th><a #ca3 [attr.data-cat]="colar" (click)="getName(ca3.dataset.cat)">C</a></th>
      <th><a #ca4 [attr.data-cat]="dera" (click)="getName(ca4.dataset.cat)">D</a></th>
   </thead>
</table>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you can adjust the data structure in the controller, I don't see the need for a template reference variable if you're only going to self reference it in an event handler.

You could achieve the same behavior with a minor change to the variables. Try the following

Controller

```js
data = [
  { category: { name: 'ARMOIRS', value: 'alax' }, label: 'A' },
  { category: { name: 'PARASOLS', value: 'beter' }, label: 'B' },
  { category: { name: 'CAMBOUS', value: 'colar' }, label: 'C' },
  { category: { name: 'DIAMBRE', value: 'dera' }, label: 'D' },
];

getName(categoryName: string) {
  console.log(categoryName);
  this.sendRequestData.emit(catName);
}
```

Template

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th *ngFor="let item of data">
      <a (mouseup)="getName(item.category.name)">{{ item.label }}</a>
    </th>
  </thead>
</table>
```